# Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 error, can't build my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

At some point when i did a build of my app, it came up with this error. I can't remember changing anything in build settings or anywhere like that. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

The whole error log:

```
CompileC /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.o Journal/JViewerViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Developer/Dear Me/Version 1.0/XCode/Journal/Journal"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Journal-Prefix-fcgznbxzuxzfpeanljwueagjodgm/Journal-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.dia -c "/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Developer/Dear Me/Version 1.0/XCode/Journal/Journal/Journal/JViewerViewController.m" -o /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.o

/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Developer/Dear Me/Version 1.0/XCode/Journal/Journal/Journal/JViewerViewController.m:15:12: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'JCreateViewController'
@interface JCreateViewController () <JEntryTableViewControllerDelegate> {
           ^
0  clang             0x000000010dffc472 _ZL15PrintStackTracePv + 34
1  clang             0x000000010dffc8f9 _ZL13SignalHandleri + 553
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8db97cfa _sigtramp + 26
3  clang             0x000000010d14b5a1 clang::Preprocessor::LookUpIdentifierInfo(clang::Token&) const + 49
4  clang             0x000000010d226609 clang::Sema::ActOnIvar(clang::Scope*, clang::SourceLocation, clang::Declarator&, clang::Expr*, clang::tok::ObjCKeywordKind) + 505
5  clang             0x000000010d918716 clang::Parser::ParseObjCClassInstanceVariables(clang::Decl*, clang::tok::ObjCKeywordKind, clang::SourceLocation)::ObjCIvarCallback::invoke(clang::FieldDeclarator&) + 70
6  clang             0x000000010d166662 clang::Parser::ParseStructDeclaration(clang::DeclSpec&, clang::Parser::FieldCallback&) + 1186
7  clang             0x000000010d226102 clang::Parser::ParseObjCClassInstanceVariables(clang::Decl*, clang::tok::ObjCKeywordKind, clang::SourceLocation) + 818
8  clang             0x000000010d224b5b clang::Parser::ParseObjCAtInterfaceDeclaration(clang::SourceLocation, clang::ParsedAttributes&) + 1131
9  clang             0x000000010d21c9ca clang::Parser::ParseObjCAtDirectives() + 250
10 clang             0x000000010d15e807 clang::Parser::ParseExternalDeclaration(clang::Parser::ParsedAttributesWithRange&, clang::Parser::ParsingDeclSpec*) + 759
11 clang             0x000000010d15e499 clang::Parser::ParseTopLevelDecl(clang::OpaquePtr<clang::DeclGroupRef>&) + 249
12 clang             0x000000010d1413a5 clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool) + 325
13 clang             0x000000010d13fed7 clang::CodeGenAction::ExecuteAction() + 855
14 clang             0x000000010d11243f clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 879
15 clang             0x000000010d1110cb clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) + 2683
16 clang             0x000000010d1038ce cc1_main(char const**, char const**, char const*, void*) + 5086
17 clang             0x000000010d0de0d8 main + 648
18 clang             0x000000010d0dde44 start + 52
19 clang             0x0000000000000070 start + 18446744069195571808
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple i386-apple-macosx10.6.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name JViewerViewController.m -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 128.2 -g -coverage-file /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -dependency-file /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -iquote /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Journal-Prefix-fcgznbxzuxzfpeanljwueagjodgm/Journal-Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG=1 -D IBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -D IBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -D IBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -D __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -I /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Journal-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/kd/vtqhgpcn19n889lxzsjfgkmh0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-arc -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.dia -o /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/JViewerViewController.o -x objective-c /Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Developer/Dear Me/Version 1.0/XCode/Journal/Journal/Journal/JViewerViewController.m 
1.  /Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Developer/Dear Me/Version 1.0/XCode/Journal/Journal/Journal/JViewerViewController.m:17:42: current parser token ';'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/kd/vtqhgpcn19n889lxzsjfgkmh0000gn/T/JViewerViewController-ur6W2M.mi
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/kd/vtqhgpcn19n889lxzsjfgkmh0000gn/T/JViewerViewController-ur6W2M.sh
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I think it's a bug in apple. I found the solution (though won't be the same with what you have). It's totally doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like something in your project might be misnamed:

`cannot find interface declaration for 'JCreateViewController'`

Are you sure you have an interface and implementation for `JCreateViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem and this may help.

It turns out the problem was:

```
 self.sortByandFilterInformation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sorted by %@ within %.2f m", self.sortByString,[BNUtilitiesQuick MaxDistanceOnSearch]];
```

It turns out self.sortByString, that should have returned a string, return "void" instead. I fix that and the program run just fine.

Yes I agree, the bug is very unclear. Try check the most recently changed code and see if there is any void function that is used with stringWithFormat.